# Question about whether the multivariate Stein's Lemma can be generalized further.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I read from a paper that the multivariate [Stein's lemma (Lemma 6.20)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.02180) is as follows:

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be such that for $j=1,\dots,d$, the function $x_j\rightarrow g(x_1,\dots,x_d)$ is absolutely continuous for Lebesgue almost every $(x_i:i\neq j)\in\mathbb{R}^{d-1}$, with weak derivative $D_jg:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ satisfying $\mathbb{E}[|D_jg(X)|]<\infty$. Let $\nabla g(x):=(D_1(x),\dots,D_d(x))$ for $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$. If $X\sim N_d(0,\Sigma)$ with $\Sigma$ positive definite, then
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Xg(X)]=\Sigma\mathbb{E}(\nabla g(X))
\end{align*}
Can this result be generalized to $g:\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^l$ (where $l\geq2$), i.e., $\mathbb{E}[Xg(X)^\top]=\Sigma\mathbb{E}(\nabla g(X))$?

**Attempt (based on William M.'s comment -- Thanks!):**
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}[Xg(X)^\top]&=\mathbb{E}[(Xg_1(X),\dots,Xg_l(X))] \\
&=(\Sigma\mathbb{E}[\nabla g_1(X)],\dots,\Sigma\mathbb{E}[\nabla g_l(X)]) \\
&=\Sigma(\mathbb{E}[\nabla g_1(X)],\dots,\mathbb{E}[\nabla g_l(X)]) \\
&=\Sigma\mathbb{E}[\nabla g(X)]^\top.
\end{align*}

Comment: How is the generalisation different? Also, are you sure the result is $E(...) = E(...)$ and not $E(...) \approx E(...)$?

Comment: I had a typo sorry, its corrected now -- the generalization is in the output dimension of $g$. For your second question, it seems that way to me from the paper I read it from...

Comment: I checked it myself; it is with equality, it follows from integration by parts. Note the expected value of a matrix is just the entrywise expectation, can you just use $X g(X)^\intercal = (Xg_1(X), \ldots, Xg_l(X))$ (column-concatenation) and then use the usual Stein's lemma on each column of this matrix?

Comment: This sounds reasonable to me, I've added my attempt above based on your comment.